How do I open a VSCode workspace in a WSL2 folder automatically in WSL2?
I have saved a Vscode workspace to \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\workspace named workspace.code-workspace. When I open workspace.code-workspace in Windows File Explorer, Vscode automatically open the workspace as if it is a normal workspace (not in WSL) so then I need to click on a prompt to switch to WSL2. I want to have that happen automatically every time I click on my workspace file to save time.
I tried searching for the answer online but couldn't find a way to do what I want to do.

I have VS Code pinned to my taskbar, and it shows me recent and pinned environments when I right click on the icon. You can click those to go directly to a WSL environment.
You can also hover over each link, and it will show you the path, such as:
vscode-remote://wsl/%2Bubuntu-22.04/home/username/projects/my-site

Perhaps this is the path that would need to go in your workspace file, starting with vscode-remote://? Note that the %2B is a plus character, which could represent a space in a URI like that.
